# JQuery click event on select element click does not work in chrome (problem does not occur in windows environment)

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on the select element in chrome, the event does not get triggered on first click (but after that, i.e. on second, third...). Why and how can I change that? (works in FF)

```js
 $("select").click(function() {
   console.log("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>a</option>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pv2eajux/

---

Note: click on the text, not on the arrow

Comment: Works for me in Chrome...

Comment: Works for me too in Chrome.

Comment: Works for me too too in Chrome...

Comment: I checked it in chrome and is working for me

Comment: I checked it on Chrome on Windows and it works fine. However, it's not being triggered on Chrome on OSX. I've tried it on two separate Macs and it's not firing on either of them.

Comment: Did you test your own fiddle in chrome?  (also try a snippet here)  Could possibly be because the `select` doesn't exist when you (first) try to wire up the event, but seems unlikely in this case.

Comment: Yes, I try it on ChromeVersion 77.0.3865.120 (Official Build) (64-bit)  on ubuntu mate 19.04

Comment: I modified the fiddle to handle mousedown instead of click and it fires every time so that would seem to point to the click event not being handled (on OSX).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally fixed it by replacing `click` with `mouseup`

```js
 $("select").mouseup(function() {
   console.log("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>a</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, when working with selects, we get better compatibility using `.focus()`:

```js
 $("select").focus(function() {
   console.log("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>a</option>
</select>
```

**Note:** even if there is no error thrown and some browsers in some conditions (eg: OS) will fire the event, specifications states that elements like `input` supports click events:

**`<Input />` specs**

```
interface HTMLInputElement : HTMLElement {
           attribute DOMString       defaultValue;
           attribute boolean         defaultChecked;
  readonly attribute HTMLFormElement form;
           attribute DOMString       accept;
           attribute DOMString       accessKey;
           attribute DOMString       align;
           attribute DOMString       alt;
           attribute boolean         checked;
           attribute boolean         disabled;
           attribute long            maxLength;
           attribute DOMString       name;
           attribute boolean         readOnly;
  // Modified in DOM Level 2:
           attribute unsigned long   size;
           attribute DOMString       src;
           attribute long            tabIndex;
  // Modified in DOM Level 2:
           attribute DOMString       type;
           attribute DOMString       useMap;
           attribute DOMString       value;
  void               blur();
  void               focus();
  void               select();
  void               click();
};
```

while `select` does not:

**`<Select />` specs**

```
interface HTMLSelectElement : HTMLElement {
  readonly attribute DOMString       type;
           attribute long            selectedIndex;
           attribute DOMString       value;
  // Modified in DOM Level 2:
           attribute unsigned long   length;
                                        // raises(DOMException) on setting

  readonly attribute HTMLFormElement form;
  // Modified in DOM Level 2:
  readonly attribute HTMLOptionsCollection options;
           attribute boolean         disabled;
           attribute boolean         multiple;
           attribute DOMString       name;
           attribute long            size;
           attribute long            tabIndex;
  void               add(in HTMLElement element, 
                         in HTMLElement before)
                                        raises(DOMException);
  void               remove(in long index);
  void               blur();
  void               focus();
};
```

Ref: https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-94282980